# Magento : I Can Not Find Local Code Pool

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I am trying to create a new module using this tutorial 
 http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/create-read-update-and-delete-with-magento-database/

But in the second step we have to go to local folder but I cannot find local folder. It only has core and community.

This is what it says:

```
anuja@anuja-VirtualBox:/var/www/html/magento/app/code$ cd /var/www/html/magento/app/code/
anuja@anuja-VirtualBox:/var/www/html/magento/app/code$ ls

community  core
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `local` folder in `app/code` folder with `community` and `core` folder

And then create the path using Folder as told in module. It does not matter if you are using a windows or Linux(Ubuntu), Folder structure and create folder options will remain same.

> If you want to know how to create folder through file Browser And
>   command line in Linux then please follow this:

**Using The File Browser**

- **Step 1**
  Navigate to the location where you want to make a new folder(in this case Inside folder `app/code/`). You can make a new folder inside an existing folder on the hard drive.
- **Step 2**
  Right-click the mouse and select "Create Folder." A new folder icon appears with the default folder name highlighted.
- **Step 3**
  Type a new name(in this case local) for the folder and press "Enter" to save the name.

**Using The Terminal**

- **Step 1**
  Open the Ubuntu terminal by clicking "Applications," then clicking "Accessories" and selecting "Terminal."
- **Step 2**
  Type `sudo mkdir app/code/local` in the terminal. The "mkdir" command creates a new folder in the location you specify after the command. Replace "app/design/local" with the location where you want to create the folder. If you want to create a folder on the desktop, the location is "home/user/Desktop/newFolder," where "user" is your username and "newFolder" is the name of the folder you are creating.
- **Step 3**
  Press "Enter" to create the folder.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: If this helps you please accept this as an answer; so future viewers can find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `local` folder in app->code folder.

Then you need to create all your file which is specified in that links.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to do that ?? because i even check the Mage.php file and it show local folder in it

Comment: you need to go into Magento root -> app -> code -> now here create folder with name local.

Comment: Sir but i am using magento in ubuntu could u explain in detail ? pleaseee

Comment: @Anuja If you have another question, then you can ask new question, so it will help community as well.